# Code Tests: how to add test code without recompiling?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, automated-tests, build-automation, delphi-2010

I have primitive test framework (sort-of) that works just fine in my case.

It's basically a special test unit that's $INCLUDEd in the project's main form.

For example, let's say my main form looks like this:

```
unit start;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, ...;

type
  {$ifdef CodeTest}
  TFileOperation = (fpDelete, fpModify, fpRename);
  {$endif}

  TMainForm = class(TdxRibbonForm)
    dxRibbon: TdxRibbon;
    dxBarManagerBar: TdxBarManager;
    About: TdxBarButton;
    // ...

    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AboutClick(Sender: TObject);
    // ...
  private
    { Private declarations }

    SomePrivateVar : String;
    // ...

    {$ifdef CodeTest}
         StartTestTimer : TTimer;
    {$endif}

    {$ifdef CodeTest}
         // Code Test Routines

         procedure CodeTestsBtnClick(Sender: TObject);

         // Start code testing after some delay to properly initialize app
         procedure StartTestingTimer(Sender: TObject);

         function  CodeTests() : Boolean;
         procedure CodeSingleTest(TheButton : TdxBarButton; strTestData : String = '');
         // ...
    {$endif}    {.$ifdef CodeTest}

    function SomePrivateFunction();
  public
    { Public declarations }

    Public_Var_1 : Integer;
    Public_Var_2 : Integer;

    function SomeFunction();
  end;

var
   MainForm : TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{$ifdef CodeTest}
        {$include _CodeTests.pas}
{$endif}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
     // ...
end;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //

...
```

Code test unit looks like this:

```
function CodeTest();
begin
      // Hide Folders Left Panel
      CodeSingleTestChecked(ShowFolders, ''{strTestData}, False{NewValue});
      Assert( IsOK( (NxSplitterLeft.Visible = False) And
                    (NxPanelFolders.Visible = False) And

                    (NxPanelFiles.PanelBorders  = [boBottom, boTop, boRight, boLeft]) And
                    (NxHeaderPanel.Margins.Left = 1)
            ));

      // etc...
end;
```

The only *real* restriction is that I have to include the code tests unit into the main form (ie. `{$include _CodeTests.pas}`), besides that, I have everything I need: functionality tests, stress, result & error checking, etc...

My only problem is; I now need to hire someone to complete these tests, but I **really** don't want to expose my code (at least not in the beginning), so I wonder if there's a way to give the new guy the code test unit but NOT the project code, only the functions headers, ie.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
procedure TMainForm.NewBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
procedure TMainForm.HelpClick(Sender: TObject);
...
```

so that s/he can proceed with code test while still be able to protect my code, at least until I trust this guy.

I'm **not** seeking for legal advice, I'm interested in the technical point of view, ie. if it's possible to protect my code without making the guy's job harder.

I thought about using build software (I own & actively use FinalBuilder), build server, etc...but eventually decided that *if* I could `inject` the test code in the EXE **without** having to recompile, this would be the idea scenario for me.

**So my question is: is it possible to inject the test code in the EXE without having to recompile)**

**PS. Yes, I know about DUnit**, but it's just not possible to switch test framework *right now* when taking in account project size & time constraints

Comment: IMHO you have to change your approach to make possible what you want. The main limitation for you is you're making the test inside your class, you have to re-compile the class in order to test it.

The simplest that comes to my mind for you is to sub-class your real form and put the tests in the sub-class. That way, you can provide your new guy the interface part and compiled dcu for the real class and let him work on the tests without seeing your code. 

Of course you have to re-think also, how effective she can be writing tests without access to the code.

Comment: When I used the TestComplete test tool, it was able to "see inside" my app, and make calls to functions that have no purpose other than testing. Thus I was able to run a test, and then call the function to get the data to see if it happened okay. I think it used COM to "see inside". It may point you in a good direction.

Comment: Thank you so much you guys, very interesting ideas indeed!
@jachguateless: you raise a valid point about the effectiveness of the tests, but given the time constraints I'll go for it for now. Do you have an example of forms sub-classing? I'm not a delphi newbie but I've never subclassed a form before, maybe you can post a simple example so that I can accept your answer? Thanks in advance!